# Should Presenter Is an Activity or Has an Activity?

Tags: gwt

I am trying to make a web app with GWT and I am trying to use the MVP design pattern. It looks like an Activity is pretty much the same as a Presenter but a presenter is more specific to a certain view, which means a Presenter should knows the special methods/elements the view supports.

But there are two options to do the same thing.

a) Let Presenter extends an Activity with additioanl methods needed by the view.

b) Let presenter and activity hold a reference to each other. In this case, the activity will do generic operations and presenter will do view specific operations.

Could anyone please help point out which option is more viable?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always with architectural design decision: it depends.

I'd recommend starting simple, where the activity is the presenter; i.e. one class plays both the role of an activity (driven by the activity manager) and the presenter (that drives the view).
And if the need arises, split them. Either to obtain smaller more maintainable classes, or because you start having different lifetimes (in GWT's mobilewebapp sample, the [`TaskActivity`](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.1/samples/mobilewebapp/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/client/activity/TaskActivity.java) lives longer than the presenters, and can switch between 2 presenters during its lifetime).

The rule of thumb is that activities are for navigation, and you can switch between several tasks without necessarily navigating (where each task would have a bookmarkable URL). In the case of the modilewebapp sample, switching between viewing and editing a task does not navigate between them.
Having separate activities and presenters also means that you could have different ways of navigating in different apps, sharing the same presenters but not the same activities (note: activities are already about that kind of dychotomy, but there are times where it doesn't really match, such as whether you consider switching between viewing and editing a navigation between "pages" or just switching task in the same "page").